# .htaccess protected site cannot be accessed by iPad

Tags: ipad, safari, password

I have been working on a website on a test server test.domain.com for a few weeks now. I was always able to access the .htaccess password protected site using my iPad mini as well as my iPhone or using the Simulator.

.htaccess used:

```
AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Test Server"
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/www/test.domain.com/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Somehow today I could not access the site anymore from my iPad mini. The site kept on loading, but no response was given to the GET request at all. No pop-up asking for the password either.

This was so weird. I tried reloading many times. Then I tried to access the site using Chrome on the same iPad where I was asked to enter the .htaccess username and password and it did work. For some off reason I had to enter the details twice, but anyways.

I decided to ask my partner to turn of the .htaccess password protection et voila! Access was granted again.

How come that I was not asked for entering the details again in Safari on the iPad? Where can I check how these details were stored if they had been?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider clearing Safari's cache of cookies and site specific data. This should clear Safari's record of login information used for your test web site.

### Clear Cookies and Data

1. Tap **Settings**;
2. Tap **Safari**;
3. Tap **Clear Cookies and Data**.

Apple publish further steps for clearing other Safari information in [iOS: Safari web settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1677).